# Chatbot can't be created as a separate window.

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

I have created a chatbot using html, jsp, css and js and now I am planning to have it as a Facebook messenger /any messenger on my website but the issue is I am unable to create my chatbot as separate window or a dialog box on the corner of the website, how do I create it as a separate window so that when we scroll down the position of chatbot remains same but the website in the back get scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do something like this :

- Create a div inside which the whole chatbot will exist.
- Keep the position of this div fixed at the corner bottom of your browser window.
- Keep the top head of the div in the viewport and the rest of the div below.
- On clicking the header the whole div should move up and down with CSS transition.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I didn't understand it from the third point, can you please explain it will an example, it will be great help or a short code will be a great help

Comment: Sorry can't add the code, but what you can do is place the div at right bottom with a small top part in the window and the rest of the div out of the window. When you click a button on this top part, it can be moved up with transition.

Comment: Thanks, I did it using i frame.. Its working with just adding a Iframe tag to the website